QGIS code for parameterAsTable / Reclassify by Table
I want to implement a QGIS Processing Tool that uses a table as input, similar to the tool "Reclassify by Table".
However I can't find any doc on that. I tried to search for a respective routine in the class QgsProcessingAlgorithm, where all the other parameterAsXY (XY = String, Bool, Extent, ...) routines are located, but can't find anything for a Table (that would trigger QGIS to offer a table-UI as input.
I wanted to see how it is implemented in Reclassify by Table (algorithm ID: native:reclassifybytable), but can't find it's sourcecode; neither in the QGIS C++ sources (where I found some of the other native algorithms, e.g. reclassifybylayer) nor in the QGIS Python sources.
How do I add a table parameter?

I found a solution in the doc for QgsProcessingParameters:

parameterAsMatrix(definition: QgsProcessingParameterDefinition, parameters: Dict[str, Any], context: QgsProcessingContext) → List[Any]
Evaluates the parameter with matching definition to a matrix/table of values. Tables are collapsed to a 1 dimensional list.

Most likely, this is used in reclassifyByTable. Still can't find the respective code example though.
